# installation of elasticsearch older version 1.3

Tags: elasticsearch

May I ask how to install elasticsearch version 1.3.3 in Red Hat Enterprise Linux? I tried out to install the RPM version of elasticsearch 2.3.5 but couldn't find RPM for version 1.3.3.
Or how to package elasticsearch 1.3.3 to RPM so that I could install, not sure if I am right to package it to RPM. 
I need a off-line RPM.

Comment: may I ask why you want to install such an old unsupported version?

Comment: @Val, thanks for your response. it is some requirement..

Comment: There you go: https://www.elastic.co/downloads/past-releases/elasticsearch-1-3-3